# Google place Api PlaceDetails Photo Reference

Tags: api, google-places-api

I am using Google Place Api where is on some results "photo_reference" (similar to "reference") value. I cannot find any mention about that how to use it to get that photo. I know how to use "reference" to get PlaceDetail and I am sure that usage of photo_reference will be similar, but I cannot find JSON/XML URL for this photo_reference request. Thank you for any help. Pavel

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Please take a look at documentation here: https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/photos

They've just announced this new **Place Photos** feature

In short this is how you should use this new feature:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?photoreference=PHOTO_REFERENCE&sensor=false&maxheight=MAX_HEIGHT&maxwidth=MAX_WIDTH&key=YOUR_API_KEY

just substitute your own values in place of:

- PHOTO_REFERENCE
- MAX_HEIGHT - int value from 1 to 1600
- MAX_WIDTH - int value from 1 to 1600
- YOUR_API_KEY

and you are done

Comment: Is there any limit for requesting the images/day with the key?

Comment: @HarishKumar 1,000 free requests per 24 hour period. You can increase this limit free of charge, up to 150,000 requests per 24 hour period, by enabling billing on the Google API Console

Comment: The PHOTO_REFERENCE is not present in response now.

Comment: @Biranchi check this API: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&type=restaurant&keyword=cruise&key=YOUR_API_KEY , add your api key here. You'll see photo_reference

Comment: I am using the nearbySearch in google.maps.places.PlacesService , the photo_reference is not present. i am only getting height, width and html_attributions.

Comment: I guess you need to post some code samples with your params, or something like this. Maybe you're using different API

Comment: i don't see the photo_reference either anymore. I've made a post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45750833/where-do-i-retrieve-the-photo-reference-value-to-make-a-google-places-photos-req

Comment: Hi I successfully made the API request now I see a photo. How do I get the url of that photo that is displayed in JS?

Comment: The `sensor` parameter is no more useful

Comment: @PavelKostenko... I get HTTP 302 error while accessing this URL form REST API or Android code... Any clue what can I do?

Comment: How can I get the profile image of google business?

Comment: @PavelKostenko please bear in mind that there is no free photo requests anymore. Read [this page on Google's billing info](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage-and-billing#places-photo)

Comment: Kindly tell me how to get photo_reference parameter value.

Answer (score 5):

The Places API now supports the return of one place photo if available for a [Place Search request](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search) and up to ten place photos for a [Place Details request](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details).

If a photos array is returned with your request, you can pass the `photo_reference` from a contained photo object to a [Place Photo request](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/photos) with the `maxheight` and/or `maxwidth`, `sensor` and `key` parameters:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=CnRvAAAAwMpdHeWlXl-lH0vp7lez4znKPIWSWvgvZFISdKx45AwJVP1Qp37YOrH7sqHMJ8C-vBDC546decipPHchJhHZL94RcTUfPa1jWzo-rSHaTlbNtjh-N68RkcToUCuY9v2HNpo5mziqkir37WU8FJEqVBIQ4k938TI3e7bf8xq-uwDZcxoUbO_ZJzPxremiQurAYzCTwRhE_V0&sensor=false&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere
```

Please see the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/photos) for more details.

Comment: i see the photo when I type the request url into my browser search bar. The url then becomes the url of the photo. How do I get this url? I only see a photo but I cannot use it in JS in any way.

Comment: Suppose I am using a photo in my application using this API, should I credit the user who took this photo or is this optional?

Comment: @mostvenerablesir... I found the solution to this problem. Given detailed answer below

Comment: @mostvenerablesir see my solution to the issue above for js

Answer (score 3):

please bear in mind that there are no free photo requests anymore.
At this moment (November 2020), it is `$7.0 for 1000 requests` (if your volume is up to 100,000). Check the photo below.

[image: Google places photo requests billing info]

Read more on [Google Places billing info page](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage-and-billing#places-photo).

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: The URL you should use to call Google Place Photos is :

```
String url = https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=PHOTOREF&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Refer: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/photos

Step 2: Since the above URL redirects to another URL, use HTTPClient, as it automatically handles redirect stuff.

Code:

```
DefaultHttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
HttpContext context = new BasicHttpContext();
hc.setRedirectHandler(new DefaultRedirectHandler() {
 @Override
 public URI getLocationURI(HttpResponse response,
 HttpContext context) throws org.apache.http.ProtocolException {

  //Capture the Location header here - This is your redirected URL
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(response.getHeaders("Location")));

  return super.getLocationURI(response,context);

  }
 });

 // Response contains the image you want. If you test the redirect URL in a browser or REST CLIENT you can see it's data
 HttpResponse response = hc.execute(httpget, context);
 if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
   // Todo: use the Image response 
   HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
   if (entity != null) {
     InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
     Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(instream);         
     ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
     imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
     images.add(imageView);
     instream.close();
  }                 
 }
 else {
   System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()+"");
 }
```

Hope this helps everyone.

Comment: is this possible doing in javascript instead of java? I cant figure out how to get the url from within the clients browser with JS. Im using the cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com proxy service as well (https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere)

Comment: @thomas here is a detailed article about using the google photos in JavaScript - https://codeburst.io/adding-city-images-to-your-react-app-14c937df2db2

Comment: @thomas see my post above for a js version

Answer (score 2):

After initiating map you can get place details with it's images

```
const service = new window.google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.getDetails(
  {
    placeId: "some_place_id_here"
  },
  (data, status) => {
    if (status === window.google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      data.photos &&
        data.photos.forEach(photo => {
          console.log(photo.getUrl({ maxWidth: 500, maxHeight: 500 }));
        });
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solving the PhotoReference issue for Javascript**

User @R.K solved this issue in java, however in js you need to use `fetch()`. Here's the code I used:

```
await fetch(proxyUrl+url).then(async(ref)=>{

await ref.blob()}).then((image)=>{

// do what you need to do
console.log(image)

}).catch((err)=>{
  console.log(err);
})
```

In this, I used a heroku link for the `proxyUrl` and the url shown in @Chriss Green's post for `url`. Hope this helps anyone confused using js!