# How do I get the Json data associated with a place in Google Places Api?

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places

I need to get the photoreference of the place a user selects so I can get a photo of it.  However, I don't understand how to download the Json array which contains photoreference.

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13524834/google-place-api-placedetails-photo-reference