# Resolution of places photos using js and google maps api v3 (places library)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am developing a web site which can display photos of few places. I get the photos like this:

```
var photos = typeof place.photos !== 'undefined' ? place.photos[0].getUrl({ 'maxWidth': 100, 'maxHeight': 125 }) : '';
if (photos.length) {//...//}
```

Unfortunately, when I want to display the photos they appear with a very bad definition:

[image]

**Note:** I display the photo with [w3schools slideshows](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp) and I set the photos like this:

```
var images = document.getElementById("PhotoFond").getElementsByTagName("img");
for (i=0; i<images.length; i++;) {

    if (!photosSlide[i]) {return;}
    images[n - 1].src = photosSlide[i];

}
```

---

However, when I go to google maps and find the same photo ([link to the same photo](https://www.google.fr/maps/place/Boutique+Repetto/@48.8698457,2.3318039,3a,75y,90t/data=!3m8!1e2!3m6!1s-YpgUfbEY4EM%2FV4ieuP4ekuI%2FAAAAAAAAADo%2FZU-Zo9kEh4kRF_lYAvVogb0Cbe7fJn0KACJkC!2e4!3e12!6s%2F%2Flh6.googleusercontent.com%2F-YpgUfbEY4EM%2FV4ieuP4ekuI%2FAAAAAAAAADo%2FZU-Zo9kEh4kRF_lYAvVogb0Cbe7fJn0KACJkC%2Fw121-h86-k-no%2F!7i3852!8i2717!4m12!1m6!3m5!1s0x47e66e30e4f3ae9f:0xc181bb5394e1e2c7!2sBoutique+Repetto!8m2!3d48.8697792!4d2.3319534!3m4!1s0x47e66e30e4f3ae9f:0xc181bb5394e1e2c7!8m2!3d48.8697792!4d2.3319534)), the quality is better.

[image]

How can I have the same resolution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places?hl=en#places_photos)

> photos[]: an array of PlacePhoto objects. A PlacePhoto can be used to obtain a photo with the getUrl() method, or you can inspect the object for the following values:
>
> height: the maximum height of the image, in pixels.
>
> width: the maximum width of the image, in pixels.
>
> html_attributions: Attribution text to be displayed with this place photo.

```
.getUrl({ 'maxWidth': 1000, 'maxHeight': 1250 }) // Just set higher resolution, no?
```

[google-place-api-placedetails-photo-reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13524834/google-place-api-placedetails-photo-reference)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.